# Plugin that uses AngularJS tutorial

Tags: plugins, api, plugin-json-api

I plan to make a plugin which should act as Backend for angularjs. And I search for a good tutorial for the implementation steps, but till now I did not found any good. Making some researches I found [this](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API), but about my understanding is not extendible for plugins. Or am I wrong? So how would I make a restAPI for a Plugin which on request would pull json response?

example

```
GET /collections             show all collections

GET /collections/summer      show summer collection
```

Comment: This is extremely broad and I doubt many people (relatively) are actively familiar with implementing AngularJS in WP environment. You are better of making an attempt on some initial implementation and focus question(s) on more specific challenges. There is no "the" way to implement APIs in WP (well, until that possible merger in core of that project).

Comment: than point me here -> "some initial implementation" please

Comment: @fefe The WP-API project is very extensible, see the related docs: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/master/docs/guides/extending.md